# How to add dynamic text to PDF toolbar using ITEXTSHARP

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

[image]

Hi All,

I am creating a PDF document using ITEXTSHARP. I need to add some content to PDF toolbar while creating the PDF document. How can i achieve this using C#. Please see the attached image for reference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

iTextSharp is used to generate PDF files, not modifying the PDF viewer. If you need to modify toolbars and stuff like this in Adobe Reader this definitely is not something that you could achieve with iTextSharp.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Is there any other way to add text a pdf toolbar using C#. And one more question is can i remove Maximize and Minimize buttons from PDF File header. Can i Achieve this using any C# Code?

Comment: @karthik k, I highly doubt this is possible with C#.

Comment: Can you suggest any preferable code to achieve this using Javascript or using any thrid party PDF tool. Actually this is the requirement we got from the client.

Comment: @karthik k, sorry, I am not aware of any tool that allows to modify Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 0):

eh...

Ok so how to do it.

Make template in Word.

eg of Word

```
Name <FirstName>
Surname <LastName>

Job <JobType>
Salary <Salary>
```

When generating:
Open word and replace  and other marks
Then makepdf (pdfcreator for example)

Edit:
Okay Ill show u schema, no ready code cuz little busy

> 1) Create word template  and
>   store it in safe place. 2) Copy
>   template to temp folder 3) Open in
>   programicaly in C# and replace
>   "" with ur data
>   .Replace('', 'Voon') 4)
>   Programiticaly print to PDF and save
>   it.

Comment: Hi I need to make this using C#.

Answer (score 0):

Only a plugin can modify the acrobat/reader toolbar.  There might be C# bindings for the acrobat API these days, but I wouldn't count on it.

PS: You can make Acrobat plugins for free.  To "Reader Enable" a plugin requires Adobe's direct intervention, and $$$.  They sign a version of the plugin, and only that signed version will run in Reader.

Your best bet is to go looking for some third-party PDF viewer.  I still wouldn't count on this feature being available, but it's better odds than "0".